Is it on topic to answer with science about the health effects of reusing cooking oil?
There is a question and answer from 2017 that asks for and receives food safety advice about the reuse of cooking fat.  While in the context of the question, there is likely to be little health risk, the answer goes much further than this and claims:

Assuming it's only used for safe food, oil will taste bad long before it will become unsafe (if it ever really does).

I think this advice is wrong and potentially dangerous.  It is well recognised that heavily reusing cooking oil is a significant global health burden (references below).
One solution would be to provide an answer countering these claims, providing appropriate references.  However I think if I made such a reply I would get deleted as health advice.  Is there a more appropriate response?  Should I make the reply anyway?

Nutritional and Physiological Effects of Used Frying Oils and Fats
Evaluation of the deleterious health effects of consumption of repeatedly heated vegetable oil
Deep frying cooking oils promote the high risk of metastases in the breast-A critical review
Consumption of reused vegetable oil intensifies BRCA1 mutations
Impact of consumption of repeatedly heated cooking oils on the incidence of various cancers- A critical review


The answer you linked to is dealing with food safety, not giving health advice.
Food safety focuses on the (potential) presence of substances or organisms in foods or ingredients that will have a more or less immediate negative impact, causing physical symptoms and sometimes requiring medical treatment. Food safety is part of good kitchen and hygiene practices. This is part of this site’s scope and ok in questions and answers.
The links you listed deal with mid- and long-term effects and health risks. A single incident of exposure will typically have no immediate impact. This is the area of health advice left to the expertise of scientists and medical professionals, and not within the scope of the site. So please don’t post an answer with your well-researched links, thank you.
In the given context, the answer is perfectly correct, because it explains why pathogens (-> again food safety) can’t survive in the oil. If you encounter a phrasing where you think the answer may be misread, please don’t add health advice, instead rather do a small edit to clarify that it’s about food safety only. In my opinion it’s not necessary in this case, but of course this is a community, so improvements are always welcome.
